# Long table - How can I shrink it without destroying the formatting and how can I wrap the titles of the columns?

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

I have this long table and I am struggling to find a way a) to wrap the titles of the 3rd and 4th column into two lines (Transmitted data that was
     unencrypted & Third party domains)and b) I also I haven't found a way to shrink the table without destroying the formatting. Any suggestions?

Thank you

```
 \begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c | c | c|} \hline \rowcolor{orange}

 \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Application} & Transmitted data that was
 unencrypted & Third party domains\\ \hline \endfirsthead

 \hline \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continuation of Table
 \ref{long:unencrypted}}\\ \hline \rowcolor{orange} \textbf{Category} &
 \textbf{Application} & Transmitted data that was
 unencrypted & Third party domains\\ \hline \endhead

 \hline \endfoot \endlastfoot

   \multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{Business}} & Adobe Reader & something &
 something \\ \cline{2-4}
     & ADP Mobile Solutions & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Dropbox & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Facebook Pages & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Indeed Jobs & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}    
     & Reed.co.uk & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Smart Scan Express & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}

     \end{long table}
```

PS. This is how it looks now..Why don't I get the colour at the end of the column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\thead` command from `makecell`. Ir allows linebreaks and a common formatting of column heads. dded an `\extrarowheight` so the vertical spacing doesn't look so tight:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain,font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage{multirow, ltablex, colortbl, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize, \bfseries}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
...
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{| c | c | c | >{\arraybackslash}c|} \hline \rowcolor{orange}

 \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Application} &\thead{ Transmitted data\\ that was
 unencrypted} & \thead{Third party \\domains}\\ \hline \endfirsthead

 \hline \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continuation of Table
 \ref{long:unencrypted}}\\ \hline \rowcolor{orange} \textbf{Category} &
 \textbf{Application} &\thead{ Transmitted data \\that was
 unencrypted} & \thead{Third party \\domains}\\ \hline \endhead

 \hline \endfoot \endlastfoot

   \multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{Business}} & Adobe Reader & something &
 something \\ \cline{2-4}
     & ADP Mobile Solutions & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Dropbox & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Facebook Pages & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Indeed Jobs & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
     & Reed.co.uk & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}
    & Smart Scan Express & 26 & 4 \\ \cline{2-4}

     \end{longtable}

...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok there is a small problem now though! Please see edited..

Comment: I had the same problem when trying a variant, but it was due to a lost letter on copy-paste. Did you compile exactly the code in my post?